# Deadlock in INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE

Tags: mysql-5.6, deadlock, bulk-insert

We have a table defined like this:

```
CREATE TABLE ipsum ( 
    id char(40) NOT NULL, 
    source char(40) NOT NULL, 
    ip_address varbinary(16) NOT NULL, 
    port smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL, 
    percentage decimal(5,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00', 
    first_date datetime NOT NULL, 
    last_date datetime NOT NULL, 
    p0 tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    p1 tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0', 
    blocked tinyint(1) NOT NULL, 
    created datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 
    country varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL, 
    continent varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL, 
    note varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL, 
    PRIMARY KEY (id), 
    KEY idx_first_seen_peer (first_date), 
    KEY idx_last_seen_peer (last_date), 
    KEY ipsum (source,ip_address,port) 
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

We are doing bulk inserts into this table in batches of up to 15,000 records at a time. Inserts are structured like this:

```
INSERT INTO ipsum (id, source, ip_address, port, percentage, first_date, last_date, p0, p1, country, continent, note, blocked) 
VALUES {{ 15000 legitimate values here sorted alphabetically by the id field }} 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
p0 = p0 OR VALUES(p0), 
p1 = p1 OR VALUES(p1), 
last_date = GREATEST(last_date, VALUES(last_date)), 
first_date = LEAST(first_date, VALUES(first_date)), 
percentage = GREATEST(percentage, VALUES(percentage));
```

The records in the `VALUES` set have been ordered by id alphabetically.

When we reach a *very high* rate of input with multiple instances of the query running we start to see deadlocks:

> Error: ER_LOCK_DEADLOCK: Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction]

No other statements are being executed against the table -- only the inserts as described above.

How can I modify the insert query to prevent the deadlocks?

Answer (score 4):

Following the [MySQL recommendations](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-deadlocks-handling.html), some options I'd consider:

- Check the `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS` to see what the deadlock is on.
- Convert the `INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` into a `SELECT` then `INSERT` or `UPDATE`.
- Reduce the size of the batches so they are quicker.
- Reduce the concurrency.

What is the relation between the ids in the concurrent batches?  Do the ranges of ids overlap?

Answer (score 0):

Even though "show processlist" may show all processes as sleeping doesn't necessarily mean the table isn't locked by another process.

```
 show open tables where name_locked=1;

 select *
   from performance_schema.table_lock_waits_summary_by_table
  where object_schema=@db
    and object_name=@tab
 \G
```